# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null! - I believe eclipse cannot find png file

Tags: java

I have looked up multiple other answers and YouTube videos and moved my PNG image into each possible folder and nothing has worked, I still receive the error:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!. 
Currently I am on Mac and using eclipse and the PNG file is within an images file which is on the same level as bin and src.

This is my code:

```
testImage = loadImage("Images/GrassTile.png");

private BufferedImage loadImage(String path)
{
    try 
    {
        BufferedImage loadedImage = ImageIO.read(Game.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path));
        BufferedImage formattedImage = new BufferedImage(loadedImage.getWidth(), loadedImage.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        formattedImage.getGraphics().drawImage(loadedImage, 0, 0, null);

        return formattedImage;
    }
    catch(IOException exception) 
    {
        exception.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Please help, this is killing me,
Thank you.

Comment: where is the exception thrown? have you checked whether or not path is null or not?

Comment: Exception is thrown: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1348)
 at Game.loadImage(Game.java:50)
 at Game.<init>(Game.java:41)
 at Game.main(Game.java:123)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I attempted to try on my home pc instead of my Mac and placing the "images" file which contains the "GrassTIle.png" file into the "src" file worked and I did not receive any errors. So I started a fresh on my Mac and I did not use the default package (I do not know if this would have had an effect however I am just going through the steps of what I done) I then created an "images" file within "src/com/raymond" which held the "GrassTile.png". I then used the path "/com/raymond/images/GrassTile.png" and I did not receive any errors and was able to render the image after I refreshed the package. I can't really see what the error was but it is now fixed. Thank you everyone who helped.

Answer (score 0):

Please, can you test if you can put 'images' folder inside src. After that change the path to "/images/GrassTile.png" and see if there is difference.

The initial '/' should point to the root of the class loader directory which should be 'src'. After that it will try to find folder 'images' with file 'GrassTile.png'

Comment: I did as you suggested, i places the "images" file which contains the "GrassTIle.png" into the "src" file and used the path you provided however i still received the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The message `input == null` means that `read` is being called with `null` - your code is not finding the image (don't blame Eclipse [for that]).

You are using the class loader to get it as an image, so it must be on the class path, that is, `Images` must be inside the `bin` folder, assuming that is the folder where the class files are located (including package structure).

Since you are using Eclipse, you can (must) create the Images folder in `src` and it will be copied to `bin` when compiling. Alternative, have a resource folder, added as an additional folder to the build path of the project, with the `Images` folder inside.

<sup>cheap trick to find out where java is searching (not reliable, more than one directory in the class path):</sup> `System.out.println(LoadImage.class.getClassLoader().getResource("."));`

Note: you can also call `getResourceAsStream` from the class, without calling `getClassLoader` - in that case, the search will start inside your package:

```
BufferedImage loadedImage = ImageIO.read(Game.class.getResourceAsStream(path));
```

in that case the `Images` folder must be in the same folder (package) as the class file (java file); unless the path starts with `/`. This is useful if you want to keep the resources *in the package*.

Comment: Yes i thought that was the problem thank you, i attempted placing "images" within "src" and i used the path "/images/GrassTile.png" and i still received the same error. I also called getResourceAsStream and nothing changed.